# R: Add a new column to my dataframe by its name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset (Y) with different group names (Real.Madrid, Chelsea, Manchester...) and a different value for each one:

```
   Real.Madrid      Chelsea         Manchester 
      420             446              339 
      PSG            Barcelona          Ajax 
      106             191             394
```

The type of this dataset is the next one:

```
num [1:6(1d)] 420 446 339 106 192 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
..$ : chr [1:6] "Real.Madrid" "Chelsea" "Manchester" "PSG" ...
```

I also have a dataframe (df1):

```
    X    Team
1   2    Real.Madrid
2   3    Real Madrid 
3   5    Ajax
4   2    Barcelona
5   1    Manchester
6   3    PSG
7   6    Chelsea
```

My objective is to append the first dataset into the dataframe, and matching the team names, add a new column with the numeric values of the first dataset:

```
    X    Team            Y
1   2    Real.Madrid    420
2   3    Real Madrid    420
3   5    Ajax           394
4   2    Barcelona      191
5   1    Manchester     339
6   3    PSG            106
7   6    Chelsea        446
```

How could I merge that values, matching the team name with the column "Team"?

Comment: Please post `dput` for your example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can take advantages of named vector `Y`, e.g.,

```
df <- within(
  df,
  Y <- Y[Team]
)
```

such that

```
  X        Team   Y
1 2 Real.Madrid 420
2 3 Real.Madrid 420
3 5        Ajax 394
4 2   Barcelona 191
5 1  Manchester 339
6 3         PSG 106
7 6     Chelsea 446
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(X = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L), Team = c("Real.Madrid", 
"Real.Madrid", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Manchester", "PSG", "Chelsea"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
"6", "7"))
> dput(Y)
c(Real.Madrid = 420, Chelsea = 446, Manchester = 339, PSG = 106, 
Barcelona = 191, Ajax = 394)
```

Comment: Hi, when I execute this, a preview of the dataframe is shown, with the column "Y" in it. But when I open again the dataframe, that column is gone. Why is that?

Comment: @Jusep I guess you missed assigning the above code to `df`, e.g., `df <- `. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

We can `stack` the named vector into a two column dataset with the "ind" as the column names and the 'values' as the second column, then with `merge` do a left join (`all.x = TRUE`) in `base R`

```
out <- merge(df1, stack(Y), by.x = 'Team', by.y = "ind", all.x = TRUE) 
names(out)[names(out) == 'values'] <- "Y"
```

-output

```
out
#         Team X   Y
#1        Ajax 5 394
#2   Barcelona 2 191
#3     Chelsea 6 446
#4  Manchester 1 339
#5         PSG 3 106
#6 Real.Madrid 2 420
#7 Real.Madrid 3 420
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` using `enframe` and `right_join`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
enframe(Y, name = "Team", value = 'Y') %>%
     right_join(df1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  Team            Y     X
#  <chr>       <dbl> <int>
#1 Real.Madrid   420     2
#2 Real.Madrid   420     3
#3 Chelsea       446     6
#4 Manchester    339     1
#5 PSG           106     3
#6 Barcelona     191     2
#7 Ajax          394     5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L), Team = c("Real.Madrid", 
"Real.Madrid", "Ajax", "Barcelona", "Manchester", "PSG", "Chelsea"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7"))

Y <- c(Real.Madrid = 420, Chelsea = 446, Manchester = 339, PSG = 106, 
Barcelona = 191, Ajax = 394)
```